# How to plot histogram using statevector simulator?

Tags: quantum-state, simulation, qasm

I'm trying to run my quantum circuit and plot the simulation result (counts) using the statevector simulator (to avoid 'shot noise'). However, instead of a 2-d histogram, the examples on Qiskit textbook associated with statevector simulator used 'plot_state_city' (which generates 3-d pictures). I'm wondering how can I generate the histogram. Here's part of my code:

[image]

The output statevector isn't the correct one, so the corresponding histogram (and counts) is not what I desired. However, if I use the qasm-simulator, I can get the result I want:
[image]

Is there a way I can get the similar histogram using the statevector simulator? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to tell without looking at your circuit, but I believe this is because your circuit contains a measurement in it.
(edit: if there were no measurements the qasm simulator wouldn't work, so you obviously have a measurement happening in your circuit)

The `statevector_simulator` simply gives you the state generated by your circuit. If you have a measurement in there, it will collapse any superposition generated prior to it and you will only see the outcome of the measurement. As you have rightly discovered, using this to plot a histogram is of no use because the `get_counts` method will return something that looks like `{'measurement_outcome' : 1}`. However, the `qasm_simulator` performs as many measurement shots as you tell it to and aggregates the results in `counts`, which makes it useful for plotting histograms.

So if you want to plot a histogram and you need to use the `statevector_simulator`, remove the measurements from the circuit. If you don't want to mess with the circuit itself, there's a handy method called [remove_final_measurements](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.remove_final_measurements.html) that you can pass to execute as follows:

```
execute(qc.remove_final_measurements(inplace=False), backend=simulator)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, so can I understand the statevector_simulator simulator as it only gives a single shot so the measurement at the end of the circuit collapses the wavefunction? I deleted the measurement at the end of my circuit but the 'counts' still have the same result as before. Should I plot the histogram without using counts? Is there a way I can plot the 'sv' in my code? Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! When you say you want to plot `sv`, I assume that means you want to plot the probabilities associated with the statevector? You don't have to do anything more than `counts = execute(qc, simulator).result().get_counts()` and pass that to `plot_histogram`...

Comment: Thanks! Yes I'm hoping to plot the probabilities associated with the statevector. I tried that and deleted the measurement in my circuit but it still shows a single state 0000 with probability 1.

Comment: That's funny, I just tried it out with the following code and it works fine:
`q = QuantumCircuit(1)
q.h(0)
plot_histogram(execute(q, backend=statevector_sim).result().get_counts())
`
Perhaps you could share your code?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, Statevector_simulator is a perfect simulator. It's going through all the linear algebra, do the actual math, instead of mimicking the quantum computer. Therefore, you won't have the probabilities distribution like qasm_simulator,  or like when you run on the quantum hardware. The statevector simulator will output the statevector of the final quantum state, as the name suggested.